# overiding flex candlestick chart itemrenderer

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, charts, mxml

I am trying to override a candlestick chart item renderer but cannot issue base class rendering on top of my own

from the flex api help:

```
itemRenderer
Type: mx.core.IFactory CSS Inheritance: No
Language Version: ActionScript 3.0  Product Version: Flex 3  Runtime Versions: Flash9, AIR 1.1 

A factory that represents the class the series will use to represent individual items on the chart. This class is instantiated once for each element in the chart. Classes used as an itemRenderer should implement the IFlexDisplayObject, ISimpleStyleClient, and IDataRenderer interfaces. The data property is assigned the chartItem that the skin instance renders.
```

as file declaration for custom renderer:

```
package { // Empty package.

  import mx.charts.series.items.HLOCSeriesItem;
  import mx.core.IDataRenderer;
  import mx.core.IFlexDisplayObject;
  import mx.styles.ISimpleStyleClient;
  import flash.display.Graphics;
  import mx.charts.chartClasses.HLOCSeriesBase;
  import mx.charts.series.CandlestickSeries;

  public class CycleColorRenderer extends HLOCSeriesBase 

     implements IFlexDisplayObject, ISimpleStyleClient, IDataRenderer {

     private var colors:Array = [0xCCCC99,0x999933,0x999966];
     private var _chartItem:HLOCSeriesItem;

     public function CycleColorRenderer() {
        super();
     }

     public function get data():Object {
        return _chartItem;
     }

     public function set data(value:Object):void {
        _chartItem = value as HLOCSeriesItem; 
        invalidateDisplayList();
     }

     override protected function
        updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number,unscaledHeight:Number):void {
           super.updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
/*           var g:Graphics = graphics;

           g.clear();  
           g.beginFill(colors[(_chartItem == null)? 0:0]);
           g.drawRect(0, 0, unscaledWidth, unscaledHeight);
           g.endFill();
*/      
/*         
           if( _chartItem && _chartItem.index == 0) {
            g.beginFill(0xFF0000); // Red line, you can select your own color
            // Draw the line across the chart. This is actually a rectangle with height 1.
            g.drawRect(-50,0,this.parent.width+50, 1);
            g.endFill();
           }
*/         
     }
  } // Close class.
} // Close package.
```

mxml declaration:

```
<mx:CandlestickSeries
    dataProvider="{TICKER}"
    openField="open"
    highField="high"
    lowField="low"
    closeField="close"
    displayName="TICKER"
    itemRenderer="CycleColorRenderer"
    >
```

The chart is being rendered, but instead of default candle sticks theres void in the place of them, but I can retrieve bars properties and render myself - I would just like to issue base renderer from the base class and just draw on top of it. What am I missing?